# Control may reach end of non-void function [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

Tags: c

I am having a slight problem regarding functions. I believe it is likely because I am not using them properly. My code is as follows:

```
int duration(string fraction)
{
    // X part of the fraction
    int numerator = fraction[0];
    // Y part of the fraction
    int denominator = fraction[2];
    // Checking for eighth note, quarter note and half note
    if (numerator == 1)
    {
        switch (denominator)
        {
            case 8:
            return 1;
            case 4:
            return 2;
            case 2:
            return 4;
       }
    }
    // Checking for dotted quarter note
    else
        return 3;
}
```

What's the problem in my code that I'm getting this particular error:

error: control may reach end of non-void function
      [-Werror,-Wreturn-type]

Comment: Check it for yourself. If `numerator` is 1, but `denominator` is, say 16. What will the function return?

Comment: The compiler doesn't know that you'll only have eighth, quarter and half notes.  Add a `default` case to your switch, identifying that the impossible has happened.

Comment: The `else` is superfluous here.

Comment: the `switch()` statement is missing the `default:` case, so that leaves a execution path open that does not contain a `return value` statement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What happens when `numerator` is `1` and `denominator` is `10` then it will not return anything - and using the function considering that it will return something will result in Undefined behavior.

That's what the warning is all about.

There are many ways to go about it - putting a `default` case in the `switch` statement or putting an return statement in the function (maybe this will designate some erroneous event that happened). What value you would return is a choice of yours based on the value that is being returned by the function. It is a different discussion altogether.

```
    ...
    if (numerator == 1)
    {
        switch (denominator)
        {
            case 8:
            return 1;
            case 4:
            return 2;
            case 2:
            return 4;
            default:
            return -1; // whatever value satisfies your application's need. 
       }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: @adityapatel.: This is completely out of context with this question...you have `main()` defined in the code? Make sure there is no typographical error and if it doesn;t solve ask a new question please...I will be glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

If the value for `denominator` is not 2, 4, 8 it will end up at the comment below.

(assuming `numerator` is 1)

Put a return statement there!

```
int duration(string fraction)
{
// X part of the fraction
int numerator = fraction[0];
// Y part of the fraction
int denominator = fraction[2];
// Checking for eigth note, quatar note and half note
if (numerator == 1)
{
    switch (denominator)
    {
        case 8:
        return 1;
        case 4:
        return 2;
        case 2:
        return 4;
   }
   // Got here and about to leave function without a return value
}
// Checking for dotted quater note
else
    return 3;
}
```